# I have three inquiries about the nodeList type

Tags: javascript, nodes, nodelist

I have three inquiries or questions about `nodeList` type in javascript.

1. What is nodeList type ?
2. Is it like array, when we dealing with it ?
3. How to know if this is nodeList type ?

**For example**

```
document.querySelector() // did not return nodeList
document.querySelectorAll() // return nodeList
//etc....
```

Comment: You could just look at the documentation... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: @Marc B: Thanks for the link. but `How to check if this is nodeList type ?`

Comment: You usually know beforehand, because you know what the method returns. Do you want to check it programmatically? Why?

Comment: @Felix Kling: because I have two way (I will use a condition).
`if (object is nodelist){
    //do something
} else {
    //do another something
}`

Comment: That doesn't explain *why* you want to do that. Why do you have to differentiate between the two? Why not make sure that you always have a list of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A nodeList is an object – an indexed (ordered) list of nodes. It has a `length` property that returns the number of nodes in the list, and a method of `item()` that returns the node at a specified index.

There's also an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection)

2) It is kind of like an array. You can use a for loop, but you can't use array methods on them or HTMLCollections because they do not inherit from the array object.

3) That's one's tricky. You essentially use `slice`, but it fails in IE9… Here's an article that explains it in detail: [duruk.net/nodelists-and-arrays-in-javascript/](http://duruk.net/nodelists-and-arrays-in-javascript/)

One more thing to consider: nodeLists and HTMLCollections are live collections, meaning that they reflect updates to them in the DOM in real time, with the exception of when it is returned by .querySelectorAll.